# Erases the following tag while trying to replace a html tag using Python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a word doc of following format

**test1.docx**

```
 ["<h58>This is article|", "", ", "<s1>Author is|", "<s33>Research is on|", "<h4>CASE IS|", "<s6>1-3|"]
```

Tried to locate tag starting with <s.*?> and replace the tag and its contents with ""

```
def locatestag():
 fileis = open("test1.docx")

 for line in fileis:
   print(line)
   newfile = re.sub('<s.*?> .*? ','',line)

with open("new file.json","w") as newoutput:
   son.dump(newfile, newoutput)
```

The final output file also makes tag like  disapper.

The final contents is like

```
["<h58>This is article|", "", ", ]
```

How to remove <s.*> and its contents only while retaining rest of the tag (ie retain tag   )

Comment: What do you mean while retaining rest of the tag?

Comment: Only tag starting with <s> should be removed. <h> should not be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your regex so that only the `<s.*>` tags and their contents are matched.

```py
for line in fileis:
    print(line)
    newfile = re.sub('<s[^>]*>[^"]*(?=")','',line)
```

The resulting `newfile` will be:

```
["<h58>This is article|", "", ", "", "", "<h4>CASE IS|", ""]
```

Of course this assumes that the "unclosed" double quote in what looks like an array of strings is not a typo but intentionally the content of your file.

Comment: Unclosed double quote is content of the file and . Even that should be removed from the doc.

Comment: "<h58>This is article|", "", ", "", "", "<h4>CASE IS|", ""].                                                         I meant single quote " along with "". Expected was to remove <s> tag and it worked. Thanks @BiOS the solution worked.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

You just want to remove the tags, and not everything after the tags so there is no need to add the extra `.*?`

### Here is the final code for you

```
re.sub('<s.*?>','',line)
```